# angularjs $uibmodal button are not clickable only in second click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using $uibmodal , with 2 buttons close and cancel(in the component).
the problem is that when the popup is triggered while refreshing the page or other triggered. I need to resize the window or click on somewhere in the page. only then the button are being clickable

```
function opentestmodal()
    {
        $rootScope.testmodal = $uibModal.open( {
            animation: true,
            backdrop:'static',
            component: 'testmodalComponent',
            windowClass: "testmodalPopupClass",
            windowTopClass: "toptestmodalPopupClass",
        });

        $rootScope.testmodal.result.then(function () {

        }, function () {
        });
    }
```

it release the buttons even if I click on the chrome address bar

Comment: Please add plunkr or jsfiddle for your code which shows the above problem

Comment: its difficult because it is not happen every time , i want to make sure that there is focus on the modal